# Plotting a bar plot in percentage instead of count

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, tidyverse

The below code is data visualization on Netflix data sourced from kaggle, I want to plot the below plot in percent instead of count

```
 netflix %>% 
      #removed 2021 because the year has not yet ended
      filter(release_year != 2021)  %>% 
      #transform the release year into characters
      transform(release_year = as.character(release_year)) %>%
      group_by(release_year) %>% 
      summarize(no_of_movies = n()) %>% 
      arrange(desc(release_year)) %>% 
      head(10) %>% 
      #plot a bar plot of each year against the no of movies released each year
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(release_year, no_of_movies), y = no_of_movies, 
                                    fill= release_year)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) + 
      xlab("Release Year") +
      ylab("Number of Movies") +
      ggtitle("Top 10 Years with highest release")
```

The following is the data source https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

netflix %>% 
  #removed 2021 because the year has not yet ended
  filter(release_year != 2021)  %>% 
  #transform the release year into characters
  transform(release_year = as.character(release_year)) %>%
  count(release_year, name = 'perc_of_movies')
  mutate(perc_of_movies = prop.table(perc_of_movies)) %>%
  arrange(desc(release_year)) %>% 
  head(10) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(release_year, perc_of_movies), y = perc_of_movies, 
             fill= release_year)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.8) + 
  xlab("Release Year") +
  ylab("Percentage of Movies") +
  ggtitle("Top 10 Years with highest release")
```